# MySql Select Top N records on Each Group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, top-n

I am using MySql DB. My table looks as below:

[image: Data Table]

And I would like to get the output as follows:

[image: Expected Output]

I tried to use Over Partition and other method, however I couldn't get what I want. Can someone kindly help?

Comment: Voted to close because your question shows zero research or effort.  If you try something in the duplicate link and get stuck, then come back here, include your query, and someone can reopen this question.

Comment: I tried to click 6 to 7 links after stackoverflow suggested. But can't get result. Also did 2 hours research google. But still cant find solution.

Comment: Well now you have the duplicate link.

Comment: Agree Tim. I saw earlier and thought the solution didn't fit mine. After reading again and again. I could achieve what I want. Thanks.